# WxPython Choice Field Invisible just on Mac

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, apache-phoenix

I am developing a cross platform app in Python using wxPython.  The app is fully developed, and the graphics toolkit is set in stone, at least for the time being.

On Windows, everything looks great.  On Linux, everything looks pretty good.  On Mac, I am having trouble with a combobox/choice being hidden in the toolbar, even though it shows up fine on Windows.

Here is a snapshot of my app on Linux, noting the entire "CoeffConv ..." section is part of the perfectly displayed combobox:

[image]

And here is a snapshot of the same exact codebase on Mac:
[image: missing_choice_box]

I've tried with wx.ComboBox and wx.Choice with the same effect.  I've made sure to call Realize() after I've added my toolbar items.  I've made sure AddControl is called to actually add the object to the toolbar.  It's definitely trying to render because the spacing is exactly what I would expect, given the contents of the choice field.

In fact, if I don't call AddControl, but I create the choice field with the toolbar as the parent, the box gets rendered but things aren't arranged properly due to the missing AddControl call:

[image]

As another check, I created a super simple toolbar with choice demo, and it works just fine:

[image]

So, here's the summary of things I know:

1. On Windows, the choice field works perfect, indicating the code isn't necessarily wrong.
2. On Linux, the choice field works perfect, supporting the idea that the code is actually OK.
3. On Mac, the choice field is present it seems, but somehow invisible, implying this is a problem with the Mac, or the Python distribution on Mac, or the combobox control in the wxPython distribution on Mac.
4. On Mac, I can get the choice to render (improperly but still) without an AddControl call, indicating the combobox can render properly, but something is goofy about the placement when added to the toolbar
5. However, On Mac, I can get a toolbar/choice to render totally fine in a dummy example, indicating it's something about my implementation...but I can't figure out what would cause it as I'm trying to make the exact same calls to the wx objects as in the dummy example.

I can't get the dummy example to reproduce the problem, but I'll keep trying.  I'm happy to report out some object properties if they would be helpful in diagnosing.  If someone has a clue for what could cause it to not show up, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

While I couldn't find the root as to why it didn't work on Mac, I did find an issue that could help others.

First a little more background.  In the app, we have multiple toolbars.  Because of that, we are creating toolbars using plain wx.ToolBar objects and adding them to the app frame using sizers.  This is in contrast to the more standard method of using self.CreateToolBar() which only allows a frame to have a single toolbar.

When I make a single change to the code to use the more natural CreateToolBar interface, the combobox immediately shows up.  When I do that, the second toolbar is messed up, but at least the initial toolbar works perfectly.  I'll be investigating how to get multiple toolbars on Mac, but it's a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but there's another solution to this for wxPython 4 if you can't use `CreateToolBar()`:

The widgets do get added to the bar and reserve the correct amount of space, but they fail to draw properly. You can resolve this by calling `control.Hide()` followed by `control.Show()` on each widget control, which then makes them draw properly.